# comparing user input to text file

Tags: python

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

class Login:

    def logging_in(self):

        StudentID = raw_input("please enter your student id. ")
        f = open("StudentDetails.txt", "r+")
        lines = f.readlines()
        if StudentID == lines:
            print("Verified Welcome")
        else:
            print("you are not a registered Student Goodbye")
            f.close()

login = Login()

login.logging_in()
```

[image]

I'm atempting to compare my user input to my variables inside the text file. Every time I atempt to type in a student id (0001,0002) It keeps Printing the you are not a registered student goodbye. How to resolve this?

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: Indeed, you're comparing a string `StudentID` to a list `lines` - why are you expecting this to work?! You want to compare _each element_ of the list to the string instead, and to do that, there's the `in` operator, for example.

Comment: `StudentID == lines` would only be true if the user somehow managed to type in the entire contents of the file.

Comment: @jasonharper, and somehow trick `raw_input` into returning a list

Answer (score 1):

You can load the valid IDs once when the instance is created. Then when a user tries to login, you just check if the ID exists in that set. For example:

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

class Login:

    def __init__(self):
        with open("StudentDetails.txt", 'r') as file:
           lines = file.readlines()
        self.valid_ids = set([s.strip() for s in lines])

    def logging_in(self):

        StudentID = raw_input("please enter your student id. ")
        if StudentID.strip() in self.valid_ids:
            print("Verified Welcome")
        else:
            print("you are not a registered Student Goodbye")

login = Login()

login.logging_in()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing input ID against a list, you need add a for loop
    def logging_in(self):

```
    StudentID = raw_input("please enter your student id. ")
    f = open("StudentDetails.txt", "r+")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines
        if StudentID in line:
            print("Verified Welcome")
        else:
            print("you are not a registered Student Goodbye")
            f.close()
```

BTW, as @Cohan says in comments, any character in line will give access to user. I am assuming this is just for learning purposes, and not a real security approach.

Comment: So, if i put my supply my student ID as `e`, I'm pretty much guaranteed access! Perhaps `if StudentID.strip() == line.strip()`

Comment: @Cohan This is about comparing a user input against a text file, not about security. Will you ever think is a good idea keep users in a text file? So should community ignore this question for it?